# Git how to check what are all the tags in current changeset

Tags: git, github, window

In my remote github repository there can be multiple tags created for one change set.
After I clone the github repository to local how can I check what are all the tags in the latest change set

`git describe --abbrev=0 --tags` only passes the latest tag in the latest change set. But I want to get all the tags in current change-set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick option would be:

```
git log -1 --decorate=on
```

It will show you all tags pointing to the latest commit. Example:

```
commit f05c2e0b8 (HEAD -> master, tag: foo, tag: bar)
```

---

You could also pipe the output through grep to see the tag names only:

```
git log -1 --pretty=%d | grep -oP '(?<=tag: )[^,^)]+'
```

Result:

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: `--decorate=on` saved me. I used `git log --oneline -n1 --decorate=on`